# event.PreventDefault() does not work when enter key is pressed on a textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea, preventdefault, enter

My code is as follows. I have a textarea defined by class ".mytext", and i want to prevent the user from going to a new line upon clicking "enter". But even after following event.preventDeafult(), enter still takes the user to the next line in the textarea. Am i missing anything here?

```js
$(document).off("keyup", ".mytext");
$(document).on("keyup", ".mytext", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("#send_msg").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytext"></textarea>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add missing relevant HTML

Comment: `$(document).off("keyup", ".mytext");` is not needed

Comment: IDs need to be unique, so you can just do `$("#send_msg").trigger("click")`  - if you have more of those, change to class and wrap in a div and do `$(this).closest('div').find('.send_msg').trigger('click')`

Comment: @mplungjan No it is a unique ID. There are no issues in that part of the code. Although, i dont get why the question is flagged as duplicate. The link you have added, the solution of that question did not work in my case. Hence my question differs from that link's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you've got to keyup it's too late, the newline is there.

Insert another listener this time for `keypress` and prevent default at that point - and of course do whatever you want to do about simulating a click at the same time which means the newline won't be in the text string at that point.

```js
$(document).off("keyup", ".mytext");
$(document).on("keypress", ".mytext", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("#send_msg").trigger("click");
  }
});
$(document).on("keyup", ".mytext", function(event) {
//this should now be redundant
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings("#send_msg").trigger("click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="mytext"></textarea>
```